# Label doesn't scale down correctly to 0.07f, but if I use font.setUseIntegerPositions(false), it shows both label and font in libGDX

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, label, draw

I try to make a label to display "You Win" and add it to winStage, but I cannot manage to display the label correctly on winStage. Some words don't show on the screen, and if I downscale further than 0.044f, the String disappears. when I add font.setUseIntegerPositions(false) to my code, the font shows correct, but the wrong label also shows. Is there a way to get this work? (hide the wrong label or get the label shows correctly), code uses Kotlin, but very similar to java

[YUW N    is the wrong label I want to remove, the correct "You Win" only shows when I add font.setUseIntegerPositions(false)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4WQL.png)

here's the relevant code part

```
    private val winViewport = StretchViewport(mainStage.width, mainStage.height)
    val winStage = Stage(winViewport, winBatch)  
    var font = BitmapFont()

    var labelStyle = Label.LabelStyle()
    labelStyle.font = font
    labelStyle.fontColor = Color.RED

    var label2 = Label("YOU WIN", labelStyle)
    label2.setBounds(0f, winStage.height*2/3, winStage.width*1, winStage.height/6)
     
    label2.setFontScale(0.07F)   // 0.07f
    font.setUseIntegerPositions(false)
    label2.setWrap(false)

    winStage.addActor(label2)

    winStage.act(delta)
    winStage.draw()
```

Comment: You could increase the Viewport size: `private val winViewport = StretchViewport(greaterWidht, greaterHeight)`. If the viewport is bigger, you don't need to scale down the font so much and you don't need to use the `setUseIntegerPosition` method that causes problems.

Comment: WOW!!! thank you soooo much!!! yeah, it solves the problem. I should also adjust size of other Actors on my winStage, but this solves my biggest problem!!! Thanks again :D